# How should I repair cracks in my basement slab?

Tags: concrete

The slab in question as been down since 1973. I've been in my home for 16 month and noticed almost straight away there was water coming up the side of the base till I could see it. I've been telling the landlord as soon as I noticed it which is nearly 16 month. Finally someone came out to have a look and said there's a water main leak under the slab. They fixed the leak today, I need to rip my wooden floor up cos it was bowing cos of water underneath it from where the water had finally got to the surface that way. When I've pulled the flooring up what would be the best way to fill the cracks what the water has made in the slab

Comment: Are you saying it took them 16 months to come and fix it?  Quite sure your landlord has to have someone to come to fix the cement floor since that probably might be structural.  The wooden floor might landlords responsibility also if it was there when you moved in.  Pictures of cracks would probably help us.

Comment: You're a renter. It's on the property owner to do long-term, permanent fixes to the property. Sadly, it sounds like this owner may get cranky with you for doing your own work, even if you've paid for it and are happy to leave the work behind.

Comment: Yeah don't do any work for a landlord who takes 16 months to fix a leak. That just makes you an excuse.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? _All_ basement slabs have cracks. What are you trying to accomplish? Please revise to be more clear.

Comment: Watch your water bills for the next few months and see if there is a noticeable drop. Hopefully you can do this against the same time period last year. The landlord may owe you money.